# How to add MkDocs Material icons to templates?

Tags: material-ui, mkdocs

MkDocs Material comes packaged with many icons, and makes it very easy to use them in markdown. You can put [short-codes](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/icons-emojis/#using-icons) anywhere in your Markdown, and they render perfectly.

```
<!-- some markdown file -->
:smile:
:material-account-circle:
```

I can't seem to figure out how to use these icons in HTML templates however. **How can the icons packaged with MkDocs Material be used in HTML templates?**

```
<!-- an HTML template used to render markdown -->
<span class="octicon octicon-clippy"></span> <!-- doesn't work -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Author here. I've just added a section to the documentation for how to use icons in templates:
https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/icons-emojis/#using-icons-in-templates

Comment: Fantastic. Your continued attention to this project is impressive. Cheers!